# How to call another class component in another file from a function in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have one function to be called when user selects a value from dropdown. I am able to achieve this. After that i should pass the value from this function to another class in another jsx file

```
change = (event) => {
    const accountno = this.props.accountno
    // <Callanothercallwithaccountno accountno={accountno}> 
}

class A extended Component {
    render() {
       return(
           <select onChange={this.change}>
           <option>onevalue</option>
           <option>anothervalue</option>
           </select>
       )
    }
}
```

Here i am expecting  to display the account no details in another class(no mistake in this class). Even though its calling but its not displaying account no

Comment: How you are binding accountno in Callanothercallwithaccountno component please post that code also then we may help you.

Comment: The short answer is via `props` as in `<select onChange={this.props.change}>` But there is a lot more wrong with your code... You are including a component and passing props in you `change` method... This is wrong... if class component it should be in your `render()` if functional (there is no render() just in `return`...